# How to programmatically simulate delay ack?

Tags: tcp

I need to simulate my wireless device to send in the ack package after X number of seconds. X can be range from 3 - 6 second. Is there a way to do it? I can't think of a way to do it in java.

Comment: You will likely need your own TCP stack in user space that operates on a raw socket. Perhaps you can port [`tc`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tc) to your wireless device.

Comment: If I build a virtual machine, is there a way to use tc to set the delay ack time?

Comment: You can set the VM as the router that your wireless device has to go through, and the VM then acts like a WAN simulator (or a very slow router). Although not "programmatic" in the way most people think of the term, using `tc`, the solution should be "scriptable".

Comment: Can you give more hint about how to configure my VM to be a very slow router?

Comment: There are plenty of how-to guides on setting up a linux router on the web, just google. If you make me do it, I would mostly be typing in what I google myself. If you want more directed help, try http://serverfault.com/
Just for my own curiosity, when you say *wireless device*, did you mean 802.11?

Comment: they are 2G and 2G devices